# Collecting arrays of unique data items from a bash loop -- readarray not appending?

Tags: bash

I have been tasked with processing a text file to retrieve only the relevant detail(s) using Bash. Following is the example contents of the text file:

```
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff via 1.2.3.188: peer holds all free leases
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff via 1.2.3.189: peer holds all free leases
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:gg via eth0: network 1.2.64.0/24: no free leases
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:gg via eth0: network 1.2.65.0/24: no free leases
```

I tried to read each line, test for the condition where it contained the strings **peer holds all** or **no free leases**. Based on the string, the line contained, I would further process it by retrieving a portion of the string and push it into an array.

```sh
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if [[ $line == *"peer holds all"* ]]; then
        readarray -t peer_holds_array < <(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $10}' | sed -e 's/:$//g')
    elif [[ $line == *"no free leases"* ]]; then
        readarray -t no_free_leases_array < <(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $12}' | sed -e 's/:$//g')
   fi

done < <(grep -i "peer holds all\|no free leases" daemon.log)

peer_holds_uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${peer_holds_array[@]}" | sort -u))
no_free_lease_uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${no_free_lease_array[@]}" | sort -u))

printf "Peer Holds Leases - Via:\n"
printf "${peer_holds_uniq[@]}\n"
printf "No Free Leases:\n"
printf "${no_free_lease_uniq[@]}\n"
```

Expected result:

```
Peer Holds Leases - Via:
1.2.3.188
1.2.3.189
No Free Leases:
1.2.64.0/24
1.2.65.0/24
```

Actual result:

```
Peer Holds Leases - Via:
1.2.3.188
No Free Leases:
1.2.64.0/24
```

Comment: See your question, did your text file contain `>` in beginning of every line or you have palced it here for a formatted output?

Comment: No. Thank you for the edit. This was the intended look for my post.

Comment: BTW -- this is a really excellent first question; shows your input, shows expected and actual results, and the code given with it demonstrates research and effort. Thank you for that!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. I appreciate that - trying to help those helping me with as much info as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working implementation might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[1-3]*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 or newer is needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

generate_input() {  # so this can be run by people without your real input file
    cat <<'EOF'
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff via 1.2.3.188: peer holds all free leases
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff via 1.2.3.189: peer holds all free leases
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:gg via eth0: network 1.2.64.0/24: no free leases
Jul 21 09:29:10 serverbkp dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:gg via eth0: network 1.2.65.0/24: no free leases
EOF
}

set -x # enable debug logging

peer_holds_re=' via ([[:digit:].]+): peer holds all'     # define regular expressions
no_free_leases_re='network ([[:digit:]/.]+): no free leases'
declare -A peer_holds_array=( ) no_free_lease_array=( )  # initialize associative arrays

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $peer_holds_re ]]; then               # testing [[ $string =~ $re ]]
        peer_holds_array[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=1           # ...sets ${BASH_REMATCH[@]} array
    elif [[ $line =~ $no_free_leases_re ]]; then
        no_free_lease_array[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=1
    fi
done < <(generate_input | grep -Ei "peer holds all|no free leases")

printf "Peer Holds Leases - Via:\n"
printf '%s\n' "${!peer_holds_array[@]}"
printf "No Free Leases:\n"
printf '%s\n' "${!no_free_lease_array[@]}"
```

- Using bash's built-in regular expression support -- `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` -- gets us out of the business of worrying how many fields a line splits into; it's also hundreds of times faster than spinning up an `echo | awk | sed` pipeline for every line of input.
- We switched over to using the keys of an *associative* array for our data, because these are always inherently unique. Herein, the actual data is the keys, and the data associated with them is just being set to a placeholder constant (in this case, `1`).
- `readarray` overwrites the entire target array, so you can't use it for incremental additions; use `array+=( "first item to append" "second item to append" )` instead for a regular array; or here, where we're setting keys in an associative array, `array["item to set"]=1`
- `printf` requires a format string, which it repeats for each set of arguments satisfying the placeholders in that string. Thus, `printf '%s\n' 'First line' 'Second line'` substitutes `First line` as the `%s` in `%s\n`, and repeats that again for `Second line`.

You can see this running at https://ideone.com/GmZYrV

For a version that uses conventional arrays instead, see this answer's edit history.

Comment: This is excellent, a new approach and the explanation, and I apologize for not having responded earlier given that this was answered within a few minutes of me posting the question. I never knew about **BASH_REMATCH** - will read up more on it.

Comment: A quick note on reference material -- [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is of course authoritative; and [the bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org) and [the Wooledge BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are likewise very good. If you're Googling, though, you're likely to find the TLDP ABS coming up in results; it has a history of showcasing bad practices in examples, and I'd recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here's how I'd do it, using GNU awk for gensub() and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ addr = gensub(/.* ([^:]+):.*$/,"\\1",1) }
/peer holds all/ { peers[addr] }
/no free leases/ { frees[addr] }

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"

    print "Peer Holds Leases - Via:"
    for (addr in peers) {
        print addr
    }

    print "No Free Leases:"
    for (addr in frees) {
        print addr
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Peer Holds Leases - Via:
1.2.3.188
1.2.3.189
No Free Leases:
1.2.64.0/24
1.2.65.0/24
```